# Identity server 4 deployment on Azure App Service Certificate (dev) issue

Tags: ssl, deployment, oauth, identityserver4, azure-web-app-service

I am having issue when deploying Identity server on Azure App services. Following is the setup.

JSclient is hosted locally.
Auth Server is on Azure App Service.

```
                var certificate = SSLHelper.GetCertificateCurrentUserMyStore(signingsslthumbprint);
            builder
                .AddSigningCredential(certificate)
                .AddSecretParser<ClientAssertionSecretParser>()
                .AddSecretValidator<PrivateKeyJwtSecretValidator>()
                .AddAspNetIdentity<User>()
                .AddProfileService<ProfileService>();
```

I have created two certificates one for Signing and another for exchange.

`New-SelfsignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=devsignature" -EKU 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3 -KeySpec "Signature" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" -StoreLocation "CurrentUser" -SAN $domains -SignatureAlgorithm "SHA256" -KeyLength 2048 -FriendlyName "DevSignature" -NotAfter $([System.DateTime]::Now.AddYears(15)) -Exportable

New-SelfsignedCertificateEx -Subject "CN=*.mydomain.com" -EKU 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -KeySpec "Exchange" -KeyUsage "DigitalSignature" -StoreLocation "CurrentUser" -SAN $domains -SignatureAlgorithm "SHA256" -KeyLength 2048 -FriendlyName "DEVExchange" -NotAfter $([System.DateTime]::Now.AddYears(15)) -Exportable`

Following is the in App Service settings for retriving all certificates.

[image]

This works when I deploy the auth server on Windows box (not local machine but on another server). However when I deploy to IIS ...

```
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext() | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke
```

119 | 2017-05-14 20:32:04.4131 | RD0003FF635548 | ERROR | ExceptionHandlerMiddleware | AsyncTaskMethodBuilder.Start => d__8.MoveNext => ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.Invoke | An unhandled exception has occurred: No signing credential is configured. Can't create JWT tokenEXCEPTIONSystem.InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured. Can't create JWT token

I am using Dev cerificate (not real one). This is for staged deployment hence.

Been trying this for last two days and cant get it to work.

Edit: This is not even hitting api server. This is just when JSClient Login redirect to-> AuthServer.

Can someone please help?

Thanks,

EDIT:

I got it bit further Thanks to @moritzg and @Austin Dimmer. Now when I call the webapi using the token it throws me 'IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://myauthserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.

Any idea?

EDIT2:

**Following is debug log from api server**

> ```
> 643 | RD0003FF635548 | DEBUG | LoggingConnectionFilter | MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext => <ReadAsync>d__16.MoveNext =>
> ```
>
> LoggingStream.Log | ReadAsync[2266] 47 45 54 20 2F 61 70 69 2F 63 6F
>   6F 6D 6D 6F 6E 2F 63 61 74 61 ................ GET /api/myendpoint
>   HTTP/1.1 Cache-Control: no-cache Connection: Keep-Alive Pragma:
>   no-cache Accept: text/plain Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch, br
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8 Authorization: Bearer
>   eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IkVEQTYsdfsdfdsfsdfdsfdscHM6.........
>   Cookie: ARRAffinity=e414d40c85d90229be06c3c9de2fzxczxczxc3.......
>   Host: myapiserver Max-Forwards: 10 Referer:
>   https://myapiserver/swagger/ User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;
>   Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36 X-LiveUpgrade: 1
>   X-WAWS-Unencoded-URL: /api/myendpoint X-Original-URL: /api/myendpoint
>   X-ARR-LOG-ID: 7c2afdfe4c-d3ea-dfer-9570-ffgfgfgfgfd DISGUISED-HOST:
>   myapiserver X-SITE-DEPLOYMENT-ID: myapiserver WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME:
>   myapiserver.azurewebsites.net X-Forwarded-For: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX,
>   XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:XXXXX X-ARR-SSL: 2048|256|C=XX, S=XXXXX, L=XXXXX,
>   O=XXXX, OU=IT, CN=*.mydoamin.com, E=xxx@xxx.com|C=XX, S=XXXXX, L=XXXX,
>   O=XXXXX, OU=IT, CN=*.mydomain.com, E=xxx@xxx.com MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN:
>   XXX-XXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX X-Forwarded-Proto: https
>
> |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Filter.Internal.LoggingStream.Log
>   650 | RD0003FF635548 | DEBUG | LoggingConnectionFilter |
>   StreamSocketOutput.ProducingComplete => LoggingStream.Write =>
>   LoggingStream.Log | Write[111] 48 54 54 50 2F 31 2E 31 20 35 30 30 20
>   49 6E 74 65 72 6E 61 6C 20 53 65 72 76 65 72 20 45 72 72 6F 72 0D 0A
>   44 61 74 65 3A 20 57 65 64 2C 20 31 37 20 4D 61 ...... HTTP/1.1 500
>   Internal Server Error Date: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX Content-Length: 0
>   Server: Kestrel
>
> |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Filter.Internal.LoggingStream.Log
>   651  | RD0003FF635548 | DEBUG | Kestrel | Frame.WriteSuffix =>
>   Connection.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.IConnectionControl.End
>   => KestrelTrace.ConnectionKeepAlive | Connection id "0HL4SVIU4EDP3" completed keep alive response. |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelTrace.ConnectionKeepAlive

**Following is Error Log from API Server**

> ```
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
> ```
>
> |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware+d__6.MoveNext
>   610 | RD0003FF635548 | ERROR | Kestrel |
>   d__2.MoveNext => Frame.ReportApplicationError
>   => KestrelTrace.ApplicationError | Connection id "0HL4SVIU4EDP2": An unhandled exception was thrown by the
>   application.EXCEPTIONSystem.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803:
>   Unable to obtain configuration from:
>   'https://myauthserver/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from:
>   'https://myauthserver/.well-known/openid-configuration'. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending
>   the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error
>   occurred    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__58.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.HttpDocumentRetriever.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.<GetConfigurationAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.ConfigurationManager`1.d__24.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler.<HandleAuthenticateAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.<InitializeAsync>d__52.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware`1.d__18.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation.IdentityServerAuthenticationMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure.CorsMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISMiddleware.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.RequestServicesContainerMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.Frame`1.d__2.MoveNext()
>   |
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.KestrelTrace.ApplicationError

No log being generated on Identity Server (AuthServer) itself.

I find the following bit of interest in Debug log

WAS-DEFAULT-HOSTNAME: myapiserver.azurewebsites.net

This is pointing to Azurewebsite url rather then myapiserver.mydomain.com which I have got it configured on azure domain settings. Not sure if this has any effect on this but anyway...

FINAL EDIT:

I have found out what the root of this problem. Basically in App service you can only access the CurrentUser's Personal store which means the Self-signed certificate will not work . You will need to purchase a real one. (Thumbs down to Mircorsoft Azure!).

Thanks

Comment: Just noticed your edit, the error you're getting happens when your `resource server` (webapi) can't reach the `IdentityServer`. Or you somehow messed up that URL. Can you check if you can access it?

Comment: I can access that url ( 'https://myauthserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration'.) using browser.

Comment: Interestingly there is an aritcle on Identity Server 4 docs http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/apis.html which suggests to enabling support for TLS for .NET framework 452. On Azure App Service its configured as 4.6. So I tried bith 452 and 462 as given in that documenation but it still fails. FYI I am using dotnet core for the app.

Comment: Okay, can you turn on logging on your `IdentityServer` and paste the logs here? I think this is definitely a certificate issue.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure your setup is correct? This is the way we do the certificates:

- Upload Certificate to Azure SSL
- Use `WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES` with the thumbprint

And use it like this in my `ConfigureServices`:`

```
var certs = new X509Certificate2Collection();

if (CurrentEnvironment.IsDevelopment())
{
       certs.Add(new X509Certificate2(Configuration["X509Certificate:CertificateName"], Configuration["X509Certificate:CertificatePassword"]));
 } else
 {
       var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
       store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
       certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, Configuration["WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES"], false);
 }
```

And then: `.AddSigningCredential(certs[0])`

Comment: Yes this is what we have as well. and I have put throw new Exception when it could not found the certificate. But that doesnt get thrown which makes me think this is not the proble.  This is the error I am getting... "No signing credential is configured. Can't create JWT token" !!!

Comment: Having investigate this further. It seems like using above it cant find the certificate! Throws Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index exception...

Comment: Wondering what is the format iof the thumprint. Is there a specific way to copy thumprint from certificate ? Mine is in xxxxxx.. instead of xx xx xx... format.

Comment: @activebiz If you're getting a `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` it can't find the certificate. You need to upload the certificate at `Settings > SSL certificates` in your app service. Once it's uploaded you can see the thumbprint. It's a 40 character string looking a little like this: `DB8RG3HJ9...` Mine is also `xxxx` so that should be correct.

Answer (score -2):

If you are running IIS check that the account running the Appool account has access rights to the private key for the certs.

Fire up MMC add in certificates addin then select your cert and go to Action -> All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys and make sure the account has the correct permissions.

Maybe also put the cert in LocalMachine rather than CurrentUser?

Finally check security groups/ firewall issues are not preventing communication from servers out to a domain and back into the servers. We observed a similar issue ('IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://myauthserver.com/.well-known/openid-configuration') in an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks but this issue is when running on Azure App Service (as mentioned above). When I deployed to Machine it worked fine.

Comment: Not really sure why you down voted me here. I was just trying to be helpful.

Comment: Thinking about this, and I am just trying to come up with ideas about what "could be wrong" In an App Service environment I assume that the instances sit behind a load balancer. In that case I understand that the documentation on Identity server may be useful to consider. https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/deployment.html perhaps these resource may give you some ideas also https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=loadbalancer or more specifically for IdentityServer 4 https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/213

Comment: Please dont take it persoanlly. I am thankful for your input. The question was clear about the problem being on the Azure app service and not on local box hence the downvote. I think few other ppl on github has same issue so if we can find it, it would be useful for everyone else as well.

Comment: There is no loadbalancer in my case so it cant be the issue

Comment: I think you possible need to try and make sure the cert subject names/domain match on both the cert applied to the instances and the one applied to the app service.

Comment: But this should already be the case. But maybe you need to setup a custom domain with SSL properly applied and point it to your App Service Endpoint, then use the cert applied to the domain. Maybe just now the cert names and the App Service endpoint domain do not match. Again just a guess!

Comment: I still have a hunch that under the covers App Service is using a load balancer, there is an option to wire up an internal load balancer and I think the public endpoint exposed by the App Service is just some kind of load balancer, happy to be corrected on this. I am mainly working in AWS just now sorry if I do not know every in an out of App Service.

Comment: I feel that my comments may help give others who are searching for similar solutions some help. I do not take your down vote personally I think that downvoting is not thankful to people who are offering you their time and ideas that may help you out. By behaving the way you do you just put me off even trying to contribute to Stack Overflow.